# Laravel, do I need multiple database tables for votes on different models

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a Question model which has a one to many relationship with an Answer model.

Now I want to add upvote/downvote funcionality to both of these models, do I need to create two tables like VotesQuestions and VotesAnswers or can I somehow manage with one? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a polymorphic relationship. This is built into Laravel. Documentation is [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations). The code shown here is for Laravel 4, but the functionality is the same for Laravel 5.

Create a votes table, and make sure it has at least two specific fields: votable_id and votable_type. In a database migration, you would use the statement `$table->morphs('votable');`, and it will create the two fields. You can have as many other fields as you like, but to make sure the relationship works, those two fields are required.

Next, setup the Vote model with the votable relationship. The name of this relationship should match the base name of the fields you created:

```
class Vote extends Eloquent {
    public function votable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

With this setup, you can now associate votes to any model you want. Go ahead and add the votes relationship to the Question and Answer models:

```
class Question extends Eloquent {
    public function votes() {
        return $this->morphMany('Vote', 'votable');
    }
}

class Answer extends Eloquent {
    public function votes() {
        return $this->morphMany('Vote', 'votable');
    }
}
```

You can now access the votes for any question/answer through the relationship:

```
$q = Question::first();
$qVotes = $q->votes; // Collection of votes for the question.

$a = Answer::first();
$aVotes = $a->votes; // Collection of votes for the answer.
```

You can also get the related question/answer model through the vote, if you ever need to:

```
$v = Vote::first();
$vRelated = $v->votable; // Will automatically be a Question or Answer object, depending on what the vote was for.
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. Really appreciating the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an table for the question and when you want to up/downvote the question there should be a count column for both, otherwise you want to log it that an user can only vote for it once, so you need another table for user_id, question_id and type (up/down).

ofc you can handle it with one table, but that is really worth because you save many things that are not necessary. 
you can create a table with an internal id, 1,2,3,4 and 1 is always the question or 0 and 2-xx (1-xxx) are always the answers. so you can handle it with one table

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generic Votes model/table which has a field called "model" and "model_id" and then use reflection to get the correct object.